# Library to convert VIDEO to multiple screenshot images

Tags: c#, class

Would anyone know where I could find a library to convert video into multiple screenshot images?

So I can 1 take a screenshot every 20 frames for example?
(Basically I want to convert video into a flip book, that can be printed out).

Answer (score 0):

http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/ will probably do.